# Highcharts arearange chart filling backgroudn is off if the dataset has nulls

Tags: highcharts

Before it used to work and in case of nulls in the dataset connected not nulls values to show continuous min/max lines. However it does not seem to work in the recent highchart release - see the problem here http://jsfiddle.net/ryaa/c93bbqpt/2/

```js
$(function () {

    var ranges = [
            [1246406400000, 14.3, 27.7],
            [1246492800000, 14.5, 27.8],
            [1246579200000, null, null],
            [1246665600000, null, null],
            [1246752000000, 16.5, 25.0],
            [1246838400000, 17.8, 25.7],
            [1246924800000, 13.5, 24.8],
            [1247011200000, 10.5, 21.4],
            [1247097600000, 9.2, 23.8],
            [1247184000000, 11.6, 21.8],
            [1247270400000, 10.7, 23.7],
            [1247356800000, 11.0, 23.3],
            [1247443200000, 11.6, 23.7],
            [1247529600000, 11.8, 20.7],
            [1247616000000, 12.6, 22.4],
            [1247702400000, 13.6, 19.6],
            [1247788800000, 11.4, 22.6],
            [1247875200000, 13.2, 25.0],
            [1247961600000, 14.2, 21.6],
            [1248048000000, 13.1, 17.1],
            [1248134400000, 12.2, 15.5],
            [1248220800000, 12.0, 20.8],
            [1248307200000, 12.0, 17.1],
            [1248393600000, 12.7, 18.3],
            [1248480000000, 12.4, 19.4],
            [1248566400000, 12.6, 19.9],
            [1248652800000, 11.9, 20.2],
            [1248739200000, 11.0, 19.3],
            [1248825600000, 10.8, 17.8],
            [1248912000000, 11.8, 18.5],
            [1248998400000, 10.8, 16.1]
        ],
        averages = [
            [1246406400000, 21.5],
            [1246492800000, 22.1],
            [1246579200000, null],
            [1246665600000, null],
            [1246752000000, 21.4],
            [1246838400000, 21.3],
            [1246924800000, 18.3],
            [1247011200000, 15.4],
            [1247097600000, 16.4],
            [1247184000000, 17.7],
            [1247270400000, 17.5],
            [1247356800000, 17.6],
            [1247443200000, 17.7],
            [1247529600000, 16.8],
            [1247616000000, 17.7],
            [1247702400000, 16.3],
            [1247788800000, 17.8],
            [1247875200000, 18.1],
            [1247961600000, 17.2],
            [1248048000000, 14.4],
            [1248134400000, 13.7],
            [1248220800000, 15.7],
            [1248307200000, 14.6],
            [1248393600000, 15.3],
            [1248480000000, 15.3],
            [1248566400000, 15.8],
            [1248652800000, 15.2],
            [1248739200000, 14.8],
            [1248825600000, 14.4],
            [1248912000000, 15],
            [1248998400000, 13.6]
        ];


    Highcharts.chart('container', {

        title: {
            text: 'July temperatures'
        },

        xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime'
        },

        yAxis: {
            title: {
                text: null
            }
        },

        tooltip: {
            crosshairs: true,
            shared: true,
            valueSuffix: '°C'
        },

        legend: {
        },

        series: [{
            name: 'Temperature',
            data: averages,
            zIndex: 1,
            marker: {
                fillColor: 'white',
                lineWidth: 2,
                lineColor: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
            },
            connectNulls: true
        }, {
            name: 'Range',
            data: ranges,
            type: 'arearange',
            lineWidth: 0,
            linkedTo: ':previous',
            color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0],
            fillOpacity: 0.3,
            zIndex: 0,
            connectNulls: true
        }]
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts-more.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Does anyone have an idea how to handle this?

Comment: Note that the min/max lines are fine but the filling between them is off

Comment: Can you be more specific about 'before'? I tracked the difference in version 4.2.6 which simply does not draw the fill at all. http://jsfiddle.net/c93bbqpt/3/ How should the values be connected for arearange? If you expect it to work as in the 4.2.6 version, then disable connectNulls for the second series. http://jsfiddle.net/c93bbqpt/4/

Comment: In one of my projects I have bower.json with the below

    "highcharts-release": "4.1.8",
    "highcharts-ng": "0.0.11",
    "highstock-release": "~2.0.1",

With this configuration the fill between min and max is shown just fine. 
Now I refactoring it for angular 2 and in package.json have

"angular2-highcharts": "^0.3.4", which gives me highcharts 4.2.7

and the min and max lines are drawn fine but the fill between them is off. If you open my initial fiddle and click on the chart so that the min and max lines are visible you will clearly see the problem.

Comment: Here is the fiddle with lineWidth set to 1 which clearly demonstrate the problem http://jsfiddle.net/ryaa/c93bbqpt/6/

Comment: I also created another fiddle for highcharts version 4.2.0 and everything works there http://jsfiddle.net/ryaa/c93bbqpt/8/

Comment: Looks like a bug - see https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6001#issuecomment-261875329

Comment: Issue http://jsfiddle.net/xsf9tf4r/